# Was Wolverine a bodyguard before or after fighting in Vietnam?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, x-men-origins-wolverine

In the 2009 movie *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, Wolverine is shown fighting in Vietnam, then recruited by the government into the X-Team, then quitting the X-Team, then 6 years later being in a relationship with Kayla, and then losing his memories during the Three Mile Island accident. Now the Three Mile Island accident happened in 1979, so that would place his quitting the X-Team on or before 1973.

On the other hand, the past portions of the 2014 movie *X-Men: Days of Future Past* that in January 1973, Wolverine was serving as a bodyguard for the mob, protecting a woman he ended up having an affair with.

So my question is, what is the sequence of events here?  Did Wolverine first serve as a bodyguard and then fight in Vietnam?  Or did he serve as a bodyguard after quitting the X-Team?

Note that I’m asking the original timeline here.  Though I suppose this has implications for the revised timeline as well, if his fighting in Vietnam was erased by the timeline change.

Comment: Are you asking specifically for information from the Film adaptations and not from the original canonic material the films are derivative of? Either way, in the real world, America withdrew from Vietnam in March of 1973 and I don't think they're trying to change that part, past or future. Just to mean that in the film universe, the logical conclusion is Vietnam before bodyguard. Also he implies he slept with "the bosses daughter" many times in the past, so we can also assume that was part of his future past as well.

Comment: @shigginpit I’m just talking about the movies, not the comics.  In any case when you say “he implies he slept with "the bosses daughter" many times in the past”, do you mean he implies this many times or he slept with her many times?

Comment: The mob guys come in the room and say something like "we're paying you to guard the bosses daughter, not scew her.", Logan replies: "well, I didn't sleep with her." mob guy A says:  "no?", Logan: "no.. well, yes I slept with her many times, but that wasn't me. that was the old me. I just got here like, 20 seconds ago." Therefore the implication is that this is an event which aligns with his past, a past where he has slept with the bosses daughter many times, not in succession but over the course of however long he was guarding her (all within the continuity specific to the movie franchise).